# Accessing a RadioButton and selecting it in Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am using Espresso to test an Android application. I am having trouble trying to find a way to access and select a RadioButton (which belongs to a RadioGroup) of the current Activity. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try something and get an error?

Comment: @Daniel, newbies like me need to start somewhere. These questions are the perfect bait.

Answer (score 8):

Given the following layout:

```xml
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/firstRadioButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/first_radio_button" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/secondRadioButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/second_radio_button" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/thirdRadioButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/third_radio_button" />

</RadioGroup>
```

Write a new test method with the following:

```java
onView(withId(R.id.firstRadioButton))
    .perform(click());
    
onView(withId(R.id.firstRadioButton))
    .check(matches(isChecked()));
    
onView(withId(R.id.secondRadioButton))
    .check(matches(not(isChecked())));
    
onView(withId(R.id.thirdRadioButton))
    .check(matches(not(isChecked())));
```

Voila!

Answer (score 3):

for the above solution, if `not` is not resolvable use `isNotChecked()`  in place of `not(isChecked())`

```java
onView(withId(R.id.firstRadioButton))
    .perform(click());

onView(withId(R.id.firstRadioButton))
    .check(matches(isNotChecked()));

onView(withId(R.id.secondRadioButton))
    .check(matches(isNotChecked())));

onView(withId(R.id.thirdRadioButton))
    .check(matches(isNotChecked()));
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with the added challenge that my RadioButtons were generated at runtime, so I could not access them directly by ID.

Yet, the proposed solution also works by accessing the RadioButtons by their labels with the *`withText`* method:

```
    onView(withText(R.string.firstButtonLabelStringRes))
            .perform(click());

    onView(withText(R.string.firstButtonLabelStringRes))
            .check(matches(isChecked()));

    onView(withText(R.string.secondButtonLabelStringRes))
            .check(matches(isNotChecked())));

    onView(withText(R.string.thirdButtonLabelStringRes))
            .check(matches(isNotChecked())));
```

Edit: I encountered texts that are not unique so my solution was to use the hamcrest *`allOf`* matcher:

```
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withParent;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.allOf;
...

    onView(allOf(withText(R.string.buttonLabelStringRes),
                 withParent(withId(R.id.radioGroupId))))
           .check(matches(isChecked()));
```