# Espresso won't find View when included with androidTestCompile

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

This is darn strange. I have an `Activity` with a `ViewPager` that hosts a couple of of `Fragment`s, the first one has a `RadioButton` with the id  `android:id="@+id/backjudgeRadionButton"`.

I have an Espresso test that looks like this:

```
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

import model.GameSetup;
import ui.SetupActivity;
import weigl.fm.refwatch.R;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;

/**
 * Created by asco on 8/7/15.
 */
public class SetupActivityEspressoTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<SetupActivity> {


    public SetupActivityEspressoTest() {
        super(SetupActivity.class);
    }


    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        getActivity();
    }

    public void testUserRoleIsSet() {


        onView(withId(R.id.backjudgeRadionButton)).perform(click());

        assertEquals(GameSetup.UserRole.backjudge, getActivity().getGameSetup().getUserRole());

    }

}
```

**When Espresso is imported in my `build.gradle` via**

```
compile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2') {
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
}

compile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.3') {
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
}
compile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2') {
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
}
```

**The test works fine.**

**When I use the intended variant of importing dependencies for instrumentation tests:**

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2') {
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
}

androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.3') {
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
}
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2') {
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
}
```

**with `androidTestCompile` instead of `compile` the test fails because the View with the provided id is not found:**

```
Running tests
Test running started
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with string from resource id: <2131230756>

View Hierarchy:
+>DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=280, height=280, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=280, height=280, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+-->ViewStub{id=16909171, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+-->FrameLayout{id=16908290, res-name=content, visibility=VISIBLE, width=280, height=280, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+--->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=280, height=280, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+---->ViewPager{id=2131558442, res-name=viewPager, visibility=VISIBLE, width=280, height=280, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=true, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=0}
|
at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:580)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:82)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:53)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:115)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:87)
at SetupActivityEspressoTest.testUserRoleIsSet(SetupActivityEspressoTest.java:30)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

It seems like Espresso only checks the Views in the Activity's layout, not the ones provided by the ViewPager.

a. How comes my test works when using `compile` instead of `androidTestCompile`?

b. Is Espresso even supposed to find `View`s within `Fragments` inside a `ViewPager`?

**EDIT:** 
This is the second variant of the espresso test that I tried, taken from [the new Android testing template](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing-templates):

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class SetupActivityTest {


    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<SetupActivity> mActivityRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<>(SetupActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void findViewPerformActionAndCheckAssertion() {
        // Find Button and Click on it
        onView(withId(R.id.backjudgeRadionButton)).perform(click());

    }

}
```

It shows the same effect.

This is all happening inside a `wear` module if that matters.

**EDIT2:** You can have a look at the whole project [on GitHub](https://github.com/asco33/RefWatch/tree/espresso2).

Comment: First, try setting up your tests using Junit: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing-templates/blob/master/AndroidTestingBlueprint/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/testing/blueprint/ui/espresso/EspressoTest.java. Also, make sure you have the correct dependencies: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing-templates/blob/master/AndroidTestingBlueprint/app/build.gradle

Comment: @JaredBurrows I included the mentioned dependencies and wrote my test according to their  example, the effect stays the same.

Comment: Ah, coudl you also post your XML and code?

Comment: @JaredBurrows Posted a link to GitHub, thanks for looking into this.

Comment: I didnt know they were RadioButtons, try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29176585/accessing-a-radiobutton-and-selecting-it-in-espresso. Also, is it visible once the Activity loads?

Comment: @JaredBurrows That's exactly what I do (or try to do), find the view by it's id then perform a click.

Comment: I know, I am talking about when you actually run your app.

Comment: i am using record espresso test, it is adding the dependency on it's own but still giving me the same error. ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reason I could think for this happening is this: 
One of the dependencies of the espresso library (my bets are on one of the support libraries) is also a dependency on the wearable UI library (com.google.android.support:wearable). The version of that dependency library on Espresso is newer than the one in wearable. If you include Espresso as a 'compile' dependency, the newer version of that library is used and all is well. When you use it as an 'androidTestCompile' dependency, the older version is used to build your app.

I'd suggest you have a look to see if there's a later version of the wearable UI library (which should have the latest dependencies) or, figure out what that dependency is and get the latest version for that yourself (and exclude it from Espresso and the wearable UI lib).

Comment: Wow, you were spot on!
Could you briefly explain why the findView method doesn't work if the projects doesn't explicitly add the latest com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1 as a dependency?

Comment: I bet the whole of the view hierarchy for FragmentActivities might change between support library versions. For example, there might be an extra FrameLayout right below the DecorView. That would mean that Espresso having been built with a different version of the support library than your app would look for views at the wrong level, hence being unable to find anything.

Comment: i am using record espresso test, it is adding the dependency on it's own but still giving me the same error. ?